# how to pass session value other page if condition true in php

Tags: php, session, if-statement

i have a  `$_sesstion['usermail']`. i want to pass this value to next page.if condition match `($answer= $_SESSTION['usermail']);`

```
if(isset($_POST['compair']))
{

    echo $_SESSION['question'];
     $_SESSION['usermail'];
    $answer=$_POST['answer'];
    if ($answer ==  $_SESSION['answer'])
    {
         header("Location:resetpass.php");

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<script>alert('Please Try again')</script>";

    } 

}
```

i want to pass `$_sesstion['usermail']` value on `resetpass.php` page.

Comment: Did you do a `session_start()` in that code somewhere?

Comment: That code is a bit of a mess. Start by adding [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and fix the silly errors first

Comment: The [PHP manual may also help you understand SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: yes i start session in both pages.

Answer (score 2):

I think your logic is wrong here. What exactly are you checking in the if statement. A session variable means you can use it on every page that has session_start(); on top.

Comment: actually  i am creating page to reset password with help of security question method in this page i trying to match answer of the question from database to user entered if match then jump to the resetpass.php page other then show error message.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions by default pass to other pages.
Make sure you have `start_session();` on top of the page you want to access the session variable.

So if `$_SESSION['usermail']` is working on your current page, it'll work on your next as well with same data.

Answer (score 1):

Get an idea from this exmple

First Page

```
<?php 
session_start();    

$_SESSION['name'] = "Adam"; 

?>
```

Second page

```
<?php 
session_start();    

echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Comment: this is not working bro. i think my jump method to the next page is worng i used header("location:resetpass.php") . is right?

Comment: @brij if you write the session_start(); function top of your code, session will exactly working.

Comment: i write this. nothing show any error. but not show session value on the second page.

Comment: i have value in $_SESSION['usermail'] in first page just i want to print on second page.

Comment: if you set  `$_SESSION['usermail']= 'some value'` exactly you can access  on another page. every page should has `session_start();` on the top.  can you put the code of that page.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GET methods for sharing your session value to next page...

```
if(isset($_POST['compair']))
{

echo $_SESSION['question'];
 $_SESSION['usermail'];
$answer=$_POST['answer'];
if ($answer ==  $_SESSION['answer'])
{
     $value_to_share=$_SESSION['usermail']; // You can share using GET
     header("Location:resetpass.php?value=$value_to_share"); 
    // receive this value at resetpass.php by $_GET['value'] 

}
else
{
     echo "<script>alert('Please Try again')</script>";

}
```

}